# "invalid multibyte string 8" error popping up for read.csv in R version 4.2.0

Tags: r, csv, encoding, utf-8, windows-11

I installed the brand-new R version 4.2.0 and tried to run my code written with version 4.1.x.

When reading in data with `read.csv` this new error popped up:

> Error in make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE) :
> invalid multibyte string 8

I figure that this has to do with the new native UTF-8 support?

I am running R under Windows 11 with English language support and I am not aware of any special characters in the csv file but I cannot rule it out completely either because it is quite a huge file.

What can I do to switch back to the old encoding which ran without any errors?

Comment: The 4.2 default behavior seems particularly tricky when rendering PDF files with Rmarkdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [default](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532197-Character-Encoding-in-the-RStudio-IDE) behaviour for R for versions < 4.2 has been:

> If you don't set a default encoding, files will be opened using UTF-8
> (on Mac desktop, Linux desktop, and server) or the system's default
> encoding (on Windows).

This behaviour has [changed](https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2021/12/07/upcoming-changes-in-r-4.2-on-windows/) in R 4.2:

> R 4.2 for Windows will support UTF-8 as native encoding

To find out the default encoding on Windows 10, run the following Powershell command:

```
[System.Text.Encoding]::Default
```

The output for this on my Windows 10 machine is:

```
IsSingleByte      : True
BodyName          : iso-8859-1
EncodingName      : Western European (Windows)
HeaderName        : Windows-1252
WebName           : Windows-1252
WindowsCodePage   : 1252
IsBrowserDisplay  : True
IsBrowserSave     : True
IsMailNewsDisplay : True
IsMailNewsSave    : True
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalEncoderBestFitFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalDecoderBestFitFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
CodePage          : 1252
```

This can be passed to `read.csv` as the encoding to use:

```r
read.csv(path_to_file, encoding = "windows-1252")
```

If you are unsure how to translate the output from Powershell into the relevant string, you can search the list of all encodings with the `stringi` package:

```r
# Replace "1252" with the relevant output from the Powershell command
cat(grep("1252", stringi::stri_enc_list(simplify = FALSE), value = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE))
```

You can take your pick from any of the options in the output:

```r
# c("ibm-1252", "ibm-1252_P100-2000", "windows-1252") c("cp1252", "ibm-5348", "ibm-5348_P100-1997", "windows-1252")
```

Comment: With "windows-1252" I still get the same error. Or do you have to run "[System.Text.Encoding]::Default" before this could even work?

Comment: What was your output from `[System.Text.Encoding]::Default`?

Comment: Also what do you get if you run `Sys.getlocale("LC_CTYPE")` in R?

Comment: I didn't run it because I don't want to change the encoding of my Windows System (side effects?!?) only to run legacy code in R. Isn't there another possibility to change something within R to run legacy code? I mean we are talking 4.1.x to 4.2.0, not about some changes years ago... Thank you

Comment: I get "English_Germany.utf8" from Sys.getlocale("LC_CTYPE")

Comment: Running the Powershell command does not change anything - it just outputs the default system encoding. It looks like your default encoding is `utf-8`. I assume you have tried `encoding = "utf-8"`? What is the actual encoding of the file itself? You can find this out by opening in any decent text editor, e.g. vscode or Notepad++, and looking in the status bar.

Comment: it tells me the encoding is ANSI

Comment: Yes, I get the same error with encoding = "utf-8"

Comment: OK so run `cat(grep("ansi", stringi::stri_enc_list(simplify = FALSE), value = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE))` and try the encodings in the output, e.g. `"ANSI1251"`.

Comment: It is very nice of you to give that workaround, but there must be another way to just load a standard csv file into this new R version without the stringi-package, this seems to be overkill... It worked without any problems with the old version...  I am really a little bit desperate here, because I try to use R with as few packages as possible...

Comment: The `stringi` package is just giving you a list of the encoding names that R uses - you only need to do this once. You are not actually using it to open the file.

Comment: Btw, I get the same error with encoding = "ANSI1251". It doesn't seem to be my day today...

Comment: You're welcome. If this actually works feel free to accept the answer. I don't know if it does as I can't test it on your machine!

Comment: Ok, so I just saved the file again, this time with an UTF-8 encoding and now everything works fine without any additional argument whatsoever... anyway, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
read.csv(path_to_file, fileEncoding= "windows-1252")
```

did it for me. Note fileEncoding instead of encoding.

Comment: As I wrote in the comments above, I still got the same error with that.

Comment: Did you use fileEncoding argument instead of encoding? I do not see that in the comments above.

Comment: Ah, you are right, I didn't see that! What is the difference?

Comment: from the help of read.table:
fileEncoding 
character string: if non-empty declares the encoding used on a file (not a connection) so the character data can be re-encoded. See the ‘Encoding’ section of the help for file, the ‘R Data Import/Export’ manual and ‘Note’.

encoding 
encoding to be assumed for input strings. It is used to mark character strings as known to be in Latin-1 or UTF-8 (see Encoding): it is not used to re-encode the input, but allows R to handle encoded strings in their native encoding (if one of those two). See ‘Value’ and ‘Note’.

Comment: `fileEncoding` did the trick for me. specifically, creating PDF files in `rmarkdown::render` context.     frankly, this was a pain;  does TEX need an update?